# Reusing user defined workflow as an activitiy in new workflow?

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4

I'm buiding an application which would be Workflow designer for user defined workflows. Of course I'm just rehosting WorkflowDesigner control (System.Activities.Presentation.WorkflowDesigner) in my WPF application, including Property Inspector and ToolboxControl for activities. One demand on my application is to enable defining user defined workflows. Logical user request is to reuse already defined workflows when defining new ones. Since any workflow is basically an activity it makes sense that such a thing is possible. My question is, how to enable such functionality? Assumption is that previously defined workflow should appear in toolbox (in dedicated category) ready to be dropped on workflow designer.

Answer (score 0):

If you compile the XAML files generated when they created the first workflows they become types in an assembly and you can add them to the toolbox. The alternative is to use IActivityTemplateFactory implementations where you load the original XAML file using the ActivityXamlServices and return those. The second means you are not reusing the original workflow, just a copy of it. So any changes are not reflected in the places they are used.

Comment: I like first approach better since it would make sense to reflect changes in such workflow on all instances. But I'm not sure I know how to achieve that? Should I use workflow compiler or what? If you didn't see it from my question I'm a total newbee in this technology. I've seen examples where xaml file is loaded and with ActivityXamlServices transformed into a dynamic activity ready for execution. This is completely different story. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you generate a project file (it's just XML) you can compile it using msbuild.exe.